# Should I use VARCHAR(20) or VARCHAR(255) to store a name?

Tags: sql, database, varchar, string-length

At the university I was told to use VARCHAR(20) to store a first name. The VARCHAR type takes space depending of string length, so is it necessary to specify smaller length range? I'm asking because RedBean ORM creates on default a VARCHAR(255) field for strings which length is <= 255 chars.

Is it any difference between using VARCHAR(20) and VARCHAR(255)? Except the maximum string length that can be stored :)

*I know that such questions have already been asked but all I understand from them is that using VARCHAR(255) where it isn't necessary could cause excessive memory consumption in DB applications.

What it is in real life programming? Should I use VARCHAR(255) for all short text inputs or try to limit length whenever it is possible?

Comment: Related reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: This must be defined by business application. Where the names come from? is it a form with 20 spaces for first name? or that is a free text field where user can copy-past content of a book?

Comment: But if application form has only 40 spaces for first name, why developer should care about feelings?

Comment: In real life programming it's almost always better to store first names, last names and similar data in nvarchar (unicode) data type rather than varchar. Because world is not limited to english names space. ;)

Comment: @Bulat if there's no penalty for allowing longer names in the DB versus the form, then it gives you the opportunity to change the form later without impacting the DB at all. Of course it also means that a programming error could put names in the DB that can't be displayed fully.

Answer (score 1):

Because 255 is now just an arbitrary choice for a VARCHAR length.

Explanation: Prior to MySQL 5.0.3 (give or take a few point releases - I forget) a VARCHAR column could be 255 characters in length maximum, so VARCHAR(255) was often used as a default. Now, however, you can go up to 65,535 characters on VARCHAR, so if you're still using "255" then that seems arbitrary and not well thought out (or your schema is just old).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to define the limit to reduce the default database size and also helpful for validation purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to use 20 characters is just as arbitrary as 255 unless you know your data.

You could use `varchar(max)` but that changes the way your data is stored and could impact performance; but without knowing more about your application and the size/volume of the data it's hard to give advice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know with varchar(20) you are telling that the field will contain not more than 20 characters.
First of all determine an ideal range for the specified field depending on what it will hold (name or address etc). Its always efficient to use as small length as required.

Answer (score 0):

VARchar (255) is generally abad choice unless you need that much space. YOU always wmake all fields the size they need to be and no more. There are several reasons for this. ONe is the row size of the record has limits. Often you can crete a row larger than the limits but the first time you try to enter data that exceeds teh limits, it willfail. THis is a bad thing and shoudl be avopided by using smaller field sizes. Larger field sizes also encourage the entry of bad information. If users know they havea lot of room in a filed, they willenter notes inthat field instead of theh data, I have seen such gems as (and this is genuine example from a past job) "Talk to the fat girl as the blonde is useless." in fields where teh length was too long. You don't want to give room for junk to be put into a field if you can help it. Bad data in means bad data out.

Wider pages can also be slower to access, so it is the database's best interest to limit field size.

Under no circumstances should you use nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) for any string type fields unless you intend for some records to contain more than 4000 characters. These fields cannot be indexed (in SQL server, know your own datbase limits when doing design) and using them indiscriminately is very bad and will cause a slower than slow database.

Names are tricky and can be hard to determine the size so some people go big. But 25-50 is more reasonable than 255. It may vary depending on the kind of names you are storing, for instance if corporations are mixed in with people names, then the field will need to be wider. If you have a lot of foreign names to store, you need to know what is the norm for names in that country as far as length. Some countries have typically longer names than others. ANd remeber as fara as first name are considered, it will make a difference whether the person uses their middle names as well and if there is anywhere to store that. This is especillay true for people who have more than one middle name or who are using their maiden name as a middle name but still go by their other names such as Mary Elizabeth Annette Von Middlesworth Jamison - you can see how hard a name like that is to break up into first, middle and last and the majority of the name might end up in the firstname column.